# Find if a key exist in a SESSION Array

Tags: php, session

```
    <?php
// i have multiple id and user_name in my SESSION, i don't want to create a new session if 5 exist.
    if($_SESSION['paneluser'][]['user_id'] != $user_id) {
        $_SESSION['paneluser'][] = array('user_id' => $user_id, 'user_name' => $user_name);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

For instance :
id : 1
id 2
id : 3

value of user_id = 3, i don't need to create a new SESSION.

I want to check if the id exist in my $_SESSION. If it's the case, i don't want to create a new session. What did i do wrong ? Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Not the most glamorous solution, but you could do a `foreach` to look for it:

```
$found = false;
foreach($_SESSION['paneluser'] as $user) {
    if($user['user_id'] == $user_id) { // look for the user ID in session array
        $found = true; // set your flag if its found
        break; // found what you want, no need to continue the loop
    }
}

if(!$found) { // if you didn't find it
    // create new entry
    $_SESSION['paneluser'][] = array('user_id' => $user_id, 'user_name' => $user_name);
}
```

Comment: Why `continue` and not `break` ?

Answer (score -1):

using `array[] = 'hello';` is for adding an element to an array, to read it you don't use [] but the current index of the element.

```
   <?php
    // i have multiple id and user_name in my SESSION, i don't want to create a new session if 5 exist.
    if($_SESSION['paneluser']['user_id'] != $user_id) {
        $_SESSION['paneluser'] = array('user_id' => $user_id, 'user_name' => $user_name);
    }
    ?>
```